# Ajax toolkit issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have an Ajax tab container that contains two tab panels which in turn contain two update panels with forms elements in them. When I save the solution, Visual Studio automatically creates two new asp tab containers with the same tab panels and update panels in them. It even names the elements the same as the ajax elements. This then generates an error because several elements are named the same.

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

I use Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

Check that AjaxControlToolkit.dll and AjaxControlToolkit.pdb are in your Bin Folder.

Place the assembly `<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>` above the page.

Make sure the ScriptManager is below the BodyContent of ContentPlaceHolder

```
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
 </asp:ScriptManager>
```

or follow this link for proper installation of ajax tool kit:
http://roopeshreddy.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/installingconfiguring-ajaxcontroltoolkit-through-nuget/

Comment: Thanks for your reply smrutiranjan. I found the problem. I was using "asp" as the tag prefix attribute when registering the assembly on the markup page. I changed this to ajaxToolkit and it solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: If my answer is useful then mark it.So that others can find this helpful.